# Poisson cohomology of germfied Poisson structures in dimension two

Tags: singularity-theory, poisson-geometry

Let $f(x, y)$ be a smooth function in the real case or a holomorphic function in the complex case. Denote  $\pi=f（x, y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ be the corresponding Poisson structure over the real plane or the complex plane. Does there exist some criterion such that the Poisson cohomology groups of the Poisson algebra $(A, \pi)$ are finite dimensinal?  Here $A$ is the algebra of germs of smooth functions or holomorphic functions

I wonder whether  it suffices that $f$  has finite codimension, that is, 
$A/(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$ is finite dimensonal.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247327/finite-dimensional-poisson-cohomologies?rq=1